# Exporting two tables of regression results on the same excel sheet?

Tags: export, stata

I am trying to export regression results from Stata using `outreg2` related to two different subsamples on the same Excel **sheet**.

Do you know if this is possible? Maybe using another Stata command ?

Comment: One could use the `dta` option of `outreg2` to save results as intermediate `dta` files, then load and export each to excel